# Yii-How to write this query in yii?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, yii

I am trying to fetch the no of records, but I am unable to write this query in yii. My sql query is given below.

`select count(review) from review_business where (date_created>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-11-01')) and (date_created<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-12-01'))` . I am currently writing this query in yii is given below.

```
$results=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->Select('count(review)')
        ->from('review_business') 
        ->where('date_created'>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-11-01'))
        ->queryAll();
```

But I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function NOW() in G:\www\ba.dev\protected\views\business\stats.php on line 19`. I am sure it is because of my poor yii query. Kindly correct my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to run the entire query and not use the active record pattern You can try built-in YII commands to do that.

```
$query = 'select * from post where category=:category';
$list= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->bindValue('category',$category)->queryAll();
```

**Explanation**: $query should be obvious and *=:category* is binding the variable *category* dynamically to the query for security reasons. In next line I am creating the query and substituting the value of *category* variable by using *bindValue()* function, finally *queryAll* retrieves all the records in the database. Hope it is clear now.
In your case

```
$query = "select count(review) as result from review_business where (date_created>=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-11-01')) and (date_created<=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-12-01'))" ;
$list= Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```

Now you can access the result like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $result = $row["result"];
}
```

Comment: How can I echo the result ? I want to show the result. So i used foreach loop like this. foreach($list as $l){echo $l;} and I got error, array to string conversion.

Comment: see my updated answer and don`t forget to include this part :  select count(review) as result from .....

Comment: I am following this link, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/it/database.query-builder But i did not find the way you told me above.

Comment: oh wait a second please

Comment: Well before marking your answer correct, I want you to please explain me the above code, if you dont mind.

Comment: no problem, please see the updated answer and let me know if it is not clear

Comment: sir one more question, in foreach loop how $row["result"] is working?

Comment: I know that in a sql query "as" are used as aliases,but in foreach loop, i am not being able to understand how it is working.

Comment: it is the property of php foreach loop , read more here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96830/discussion-between-usman-iqbal-and-thepiyush13).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$results=Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->Select('count(review)')
    ->from('review_business') 
    ->where('date_created >=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,"%Y-11-01")')
    ->queryScalar();
```